# Pytorch Cuda support not available using Jupyter notebook on Arch

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter

On Arch linux I installed Jupyterhub and Pytorch with cuda support. The problem is that I can use pytorch with CUDA support in the console with python as well as with Ipython but not in a Jupyter notebook.

`torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `false` in the Jupyter notebook environment and all other commands return `No CUDA GPUs are available`.

I used the AUR package  jupyterhub 1.4.0-1 and python-pytorch-cuda 1.10.0-3. As mentioned both installed without problems and work well for themselves.
`nvidia-smi` shows me `Driver Version: 495.44` and `CUDA Version: 11.5`. Independent of python other programs using CUDA support run without any problem. So I don't think the problem is related to CUDA or graphic driver version.

I checked via `sys.path` and `printenv` the search path for modules and the environment variables, respectively. Both gave me the same output in the console and in a Jupyter notebook. So this does not seem to cause the problem either.

Does anyone has an idea what causes the problem or what needs to have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution.
Since I start Jupyterhub as a systemd service I have a look at the service file.
There the option `PrivateDevice=True` was set. This turn off physical device access by the executed process.
A nice overview about security and hardening options for systemd service units can be found here
https://gist.github.com/ageis/f5595e59b1cddb1513d1b425a323db04